# Recommended package for making same-height subfigures?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I've read that the `subfigure` package has been deprecated in favor of the `subcaption` package. However, the `subcaption` package has the unfortunate requirement that you specify the width of each subfigure in advance. But, for the common case of creating a row of same-height subfigures, you don't know their widths in advance, you just know that you want all them to be 5cm tall (for example).

So, what would be a recommended (and not deprecated) package for making strips of subfigures so that they're automatically scaled to a given height?

Note: The easiest syntax, the better (ie: I prefer to avoid manually defined minipages nor custom boxes, and use a package with easy syntax instead, just like `subcaption`, `subfigure`, etc...)

Comment: Try to use `subfig` package: `\subfloat[<sub caption> \label{...}]{\includegraphics[height=...]{<picture name>}}`.

Comment: You can use the `subfloatrow` environment, from the `floatrow` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no requirement to specify the width of the box when you supply the content inside a `\subcaptionbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subcaptionbox{abc}{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-a}} \quad
  \subcaptionbox{def}{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-1x1}} \quad
  \subcaptionbox{ghi}{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-b}} \quad
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The width of the resulting box is made to fit the contents naturally. You *can* specify the width if you need to, since `\subcaptionbox` has the following extended usage/format:

```
\subcaptionbox[<list entry>]{<heading>}[<width>][<inner-pos>]{<contents>}
```

Note the optional macro for specifying the `<width>` of the box.

Comment: Choose this one because the `subcaption` package is the one that fits best in my current scenario.

Answer (score 4):

The `\subfloat` command from the [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package can also be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[abc]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}\quad
  \subfloat[def]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-1x1}}\quad
  \subfloat[ghi]{\includegraphics[height=5\baselineskip]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for showing how to do it with `subfig`. Thanks a lot!